# Skip "The database has no Time dimension." warning in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a way of getting rid of this warning in Visual Studio 2013 in Business Intelligence / Analysis Services project ? 
I do not have time dimension and I do not need one.